# Connect to PostgreSQL from UI

Tags: postgresql

I haven't used PostgreSQL before but now I have a Rails app that is using PostgreSQL and I want to see if I can connect to it and see if there is any data in there: I used InductionApp to try to connect, but don't know what to actually type in the fields to connect or where to find the data that I need to connect: http://inductionapp.com

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, I posted a screen shot of how it looks like for me:

[image]